# Почему возникает ошибка при передаче несуществующей переменной?

Tags: php

Почему при передаче несуществующей переменной в свою функцию получаю ошибку: "Переменная не существует", а со стандартной функцией `isset` такого нет?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что `isset` (как и `empty`) - это не функция. Это конструкция языка. Обратите внимание, они указаны в [списке зарезервированных слов](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php) и имеют соответствующие примечания на своих страницах мануала.